# Bluetooth blood pressure monitor without forcing cloud upload

Tags: android

This may belong in the hardware section, but it is the app I am concerned with...

I am looking into getting a blood pressure monitor that can log readings to an Android app.

For security reasons, I do NOT want those readings to be sent to the maker of the app.

I specifically asked Omron this and they replied the BP cuff must use their app, (no one elses,) and the app WILL send the BP data to them. (see reply below)

Personally, I feel this is a violation of HIPAA laws, but I guess it's in the fine print.

Can someone recommend a BP monitor that does NOT send data to the manufacturer of the hardware?

Ideally, I'd be nice if I could email the logged data to someone (my Dr. for example) and if the data can be formatted as an SDF or other database format.

Thanks, Mark.

```
Hello, my name is Brittany. 


Thank you for getting in touch with us at Omron Healthcare.
We’re passionate about improving people’s lives and contributing to a better society.
We’re happy to answer any questions you have about our health and wellness products.  

I am sorry for any inconvenience.
The Omron Connect app is cloud based and account has to be created to use the software.
Also the Omron units are only compatible with the Omron Software.
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any privacy-friendly app that can read data directly from a measuring device (see my [related app-listing here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/health_various#group_1175); apps with a star come without trackers). If you're OK with enter the measurements manually, there are a few solutions, I'd strongly recommend taking from F-Droid (which is focused on privacy and transparency). A good candidate then would e.g. be [MediLog](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.zell_mbc.medilog/).

Comment: Thanks @Izzy for the work you did. Maybe there is a new opportunity to build a "man in the middle" app to get readings from the devices and enter them into one of these third party apps. Mark.

Comment: Problem is that protocols are rarely disclosed, so that would requite BT snooping and reverse-engineering. [Gadgetbridge](https://codeberg.org/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge) does such things for smartwatches and fitness trackers, but AFAIK not including blood pressure.